# How to remove the space and dots and convert into lowercase

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a pyspark dataframe with names like

```
N. Plainfield  
North Plainfield
West Home  Land 
NEWYORK
newyork
So. Plainfield
S.  Plaindield
```

Some of them contain dots and spaces between initials, and some do not. How can they be converted to:

```
 n Plainfield  
 north plainfield
 west homeland
 newyork 
 newyork
 so plainfield
 s plainfield
```

(with no dots and spaces between initials and 1 space between initials and name)

I tried using the following, but it only replaces dots and doesn't remove spaces between initials:

```
names_modified = names.withColumn("name_clean", regexp_replace("name", r"\.",""))
```

After removing the whitespaces and dots is there any way get the distinct values.
Like this.

```
north plainfield
west homeland 
newyork
so plainfield
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should divide the step.

1. from uppercase to lowercase
2. replace dot using regex_replace function

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    # from uppercase to lowercase
    names_modified = names_modified.withColumn('name', lower('name'))
    # from dot to blink
    names_modified = names_modified.withColumn('name_clean', regex_replace('name', '.', ' '))
   ```